# How to load a highchart script within a WebPartZone

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, highcharts, web-parts

So I am trying to make a Dashboard-like page. To achieve this I am using the WebParts component.

For example, I am using:

```
<asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone2" runat="server">
<ZoneTemplate>
</ZoneTemplate>
</asp:WebPartZone>
```

In this ZoneTemplate, I want to 'load' my highchart (by script). The script for my linechart highchart is:

```
 <script>
            $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'lineChartDiv',
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'subtitel'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: <%=Xaxis %>
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: '<%=SeriesYaxis2name %>',
                data: <%=SeriesYaxis2 %>
                //data: [3.9,4.2,5.7,8.5,11.9,15.2,17.0,16.6,14.2,10.3,6.6,4.8]
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
```

So far I've only managed to load the complete script upon entering the page. I want it to load in my 'zone template', so that I can show it within that frame and adjust the size etc. if necessary. How do I do this?

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. Maybe there are better ways to load a highchart through a script within a 'widget-like'-frame (in this case .NET WebParts).

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "load in my zone template".  Can you explain some more?

Comment: why don't you use a web user control?

Answer (score 0):

what framework for .net are you using?, i had the same problem within framework 2.0 and i had to create a web user control, and import there all the things you need like the highcharts and jquery framework.

on 3.5 you can add it dynamically.